# ASP.Net application - Windows authentication NOT showing current logged-in usernames but NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, amazon-web-services, authentication

We’ve few ASP.Net v2.0 intranet applications running with Windows Authentication. Recently the servers were moved from on-premises datacenter to AWS (Amazon Web Services). After the move, everything seems to be working as-is except for the welcome message which is now showing “Hello NETWORK SERVICE” instead of the name of the logged in user.

In IIS Authentication settings, only Windows Authentication is enabled with all others options including “ASP.Net Impersonation” disabled. Tried running Application Pool with both ApplicationPoolIdentity and NetworkService but same results. The way current username is fetched in code is;

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Any idea what needs to be changed to get it back to previous behavior where it showed current logged-in user name instead of NETWORK SERVICE? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that someone had messed around with IIS settings so to fix it I did below steps;

1. Go to the web application in IIS
2. Open Configuration Editor
3. Change Section to system.webServer/serverRuntime
4. Change authenticatedUserOverride to UseAuthenticatedUser (for me it was set to UseWorkerProcessUser)

For further details refer to below link; 
https://blogs.iis.net/jaroslad/what-does-the-authenticateduseroverrideuser-do

screenshot of the configuration [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig1x2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should read from Page.User for WebForms or Controller.User for MVC.